# Rotation Euler in Constraints python

Tags: python, scripting, constraints

Transformation constrain have an Euler mode in Blender 2.9.
I need it in Blender 2.79.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance!

https://developer.blender.org/rBS18d4ad5a59d32922f9d70b0412da0c830baceb17

Comment: Please do not  post images of code, 
instead  copy, or type, the text into the question. Please reserve the 
use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things 
that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more 
information please see the Meta FAQ entry
[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)